# Saber parámetros en funciones de postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Necesito poder realizar un loop con el que pueda recorrer los parámetros de las funciones que tengo en Postgres, con los parámetros de las funciones necesito saber el tipo de dato, y el valor que tiene cada uno para guardar esta información en una tabla.

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontré la manera de realizar lo que estaba buscando, en el siguiente articulo lo encontré: https://www.linuxito.com/programacion/1089-listar-procedimientos-functions-en-postgresql